# Where can I get a free virtual machine online for AiX?

Tags: cloud, virtual, ksh, free, aix

I wish to test a few ksh scripts to see if they are compatible with AiX 6.1 or any other version.

A non-root online terminal would also suffice.

I would prefer not providing credit card details as a first preference.

Not sure if the free cloud subscription with AWS, Azure, and Google provides 
 [non-paid non-billed] free AiX systems.

Comment: https://lparbox.com/aix-cloud

Answer (score 1):

AIX runs on PowerPC chips (ie, AIX does not run on Intel/x86 chips).

A quick (google) search brings up the following links that **might** be of interest:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/how-to-run-a-fresh-version-of-aix-in-a-virtual-machine-with-a-linux-host

http://www.polarhome.com/

https://www.facebook.com/653524464784693/posts/online-aix-server-to-practicefree-aix-server-onlineaix-online-training-freehow-t/873482172788920/

NOTE: I am only (re)posting what shows up in a google search; I have no other information about any of the above links.